# The midline of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, locus, centroid

Triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with $AB = AC$. $P$ is a variable point on $AB$, and $Q$ is a variable point on $AC$, so that $BP = AQ$. Let $O$ be the midpoint of $PQ$. Prove that $d(O, BC)$ is constant, and determine the locus of point $O$.

I feel that it should be solved with the help of center lines, and that the locus of point $O$ will be the centroid of a triangle $ABC$, but I have not been able to prove it.

I need some hints. How can I start?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: When $|BP| = |AQ| = 0 $, where is $O$? Likewise, when $|BP| = |AQ| = |AB|$, where is $O$? That should give you a strong idea of what $d(O, BC) $ and the locus of $O$ is. Can you make that conjecture, then state where you're stuck in proving it?

Comment: In this cases the O will be the midpoint of the sides.

Comment: Right, it's the midpoint of different sides. So what is the only possible value of $d(O, BC) $? And what do you think the locus of $O$ is ? And as we vary $P, Q$, what happens to $O$?

Comment: O will describe the centroid of the triangle as P, Q change. d(O, BC) will be the height of the trapezoid PQBC. But I do not know how these should be proved.

Comment: Centroid is a single point. The midpoints of the sides  are not the centroid, so the locus of $O$ (which includes the midpoints of the sides) is not the centroid (although it happens to be true that the centroid is in the locus).

Comment: I mean O will describe the midline of the triangle as P, Q change

Answer (score 2):

Let P be a point on AB of the isosceles triangle ABC.

[image]

Through P draw the red line parallel to AC. It will cut BC at X.

Through X draw the red dotted line parallel to AB, it will cut AC at some point T, say.

Since APXT is a //gram, AT = PX = PB = AQ. This means T is actually Q. Also, if $O_1$ is the midpoint of the diagonal PQ, it is also the midpoint of the diagonal AX.

Next, starting with some other P’ on AB, and going through the similar process as the above, we get the corresponding pint $O_2$.

Applying the midpoint theorem to triangle AXX’, we conclude that $O_1O_2 // XX’$. Result follows.

In the limiting case that when P moves to the midpoint of AB, that midpoint is $O_n$ for some n. The same thing happens to Q. We can say that the locus of O is the mid line of the isosceles triangle ABC.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First we translate BP to find the Q on AC. For this we take the mid point of AB, M, and reflect P about it to get point P'. Now we draw a circle center on A and radius AP', it intersect AC at Q(why?). In triangle PP'Q, MO is parallel with P'Q and in triangle ABC P'Q is parallel with BC, therefore $MO||BC$, this property  holds for any position of Point P which is the start point of construction. In this way the locus of point O is a line that connects the mid points of legs AB and AC.